# Docker - Apache global configuration for Symfony project

Tags: docker, symfony, apache2

Good afternoon,

I try to create a project with Docker and php:7.4-apache image. My development environment has been install (`docker-compose & composer install`) without problems but when I try to access to the website from my web browser, I get a HTTP 403 response.

This is my vhost.conf for the website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errors.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The application is on a custom network on Docker :

```
[{
    "Name": "common",
    "Id": "302304f6956efb53dad1499ed44394f90a78ad4375d2e2e11b9cda5e8ae76c5e",
    "Created": "2022-08-18T21:04:44.8239617Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "69f7691d8ccd4b36d6ebab6d731ccef7388967ca7bce12c42c2b113f0d5f259d": {
            "Name": "postgres-alpine-144_postgres_1",
            "EndpointID": "82eba6f54ec7a19ddb072b599e7aa6200b54510affe6b60dfaa90ac4f6344219",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "fda67c4efa016926b164505ff022d979e7f3a368cfb78098675e8a182f0be639": {
            "Name": "api",
            "EndpointID": "7e2cfb1d998cef35c22f55eac3a14cdd27eecba211b8233633f9c8dcb5719ff8",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}]
```

When I check authorizations in public directory:

```
root@fda67c4efa01:/var/www/html/public# ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 18 21:58 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 18 22:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  199 Aug 18 21:38 index.php
root@fda67c4efa01:/var/www/html/public#
```

And I have added "my-project" to host file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

In my Dockerfile, I had this line :

```
COPY .docker/apache2/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/0000-default.conf
```

I have changed it to :

```
COPY .docker/apache2/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

It is working perfectly. The problem was probably that I wasn't overriding the default Apache2 configuration